# File not found after is copied in previous task in GULP series

Tags: javascript, sass, promise, async-await, gulp

I want to compile **main.css** for several themes. I have two resources for each theme. The core CSS and theme CSS which are placed in different folders. So I copy core and theme scss files in loop into a temporary folder **/.tmp** and then run **sass** task to compile **main.css**. But I always get an error "File not found" (see below) although the file **main.scss** is copied and exists.
It should run in series and I also tried to use promises to make sure that the files are copied.
The task **styles** starts after "coreStylesAll" and "themeStylesAll" are finished.

At the end I get this error message:

> Error: File not found with singular glob: C:/www/_dev-env/.tmp/web/scss/main.scss (if this was purposeful, use `allowEmpty` option)

Folder structure

```
/src
  /core
    /scss
  /themes
    /theme1
      /scss
    /theme2
      /scss
```

gulpfile.js

```
const themesPath = 'src/themes';
const folders = getFolders(themesPath);

function coreStyles() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    folders.map(function(folder) {
      resolve( src( 'src/core/scss/**/*')
      .pipe( dest('.tmp/themes/'+ folder +'/scss') ) );
    });
  });
}

async function coreStylesAll() {
  console.log('before promise call')
  let result = await coreStyles();
  console.log('promise resolved: ' + result);

  return result;
}

function themeStyles() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    folders.map(function(folder) {
      resolve( src( 'src/themes/'+ folder +'/scss/**/*')
      .pipe( dest('.tmp/themes/'+ folder +'/scss') ) );
    });
  });
}

async function themeStylesAll() {
  console.log('before promise call')
  let result = await themeStyles();
  console.log('promise resolved: ' + result);

  return result;
}

function styles() {

  folders.map(function(folder) {
    
      src('.tmp/themes/'+ folder +'/scss/main.scss')
      .pipe($.plumber())
      .pipe($.sass.sync({
        outputStyle: 'expanded',
        precision: 10,
        includePaths: ['.']
      }).on('error', $.sass.logError))
      .pipe(dest('build/webs/'+ folder +'/styles') 
    );
  });

}

const build = series(
  // tasks ...
  themeStylesAll,
  coreStylesAll,
  styles,
  // tasks ....
);
```

**UPDATE**

`.on('end', resolve)` seems to be to proper solution.

```
function coreStyles(folder) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      src( 'src/core/scss/**/*')
      .pipe( dest('.tmp/themes/'+ folder +'/scss') )
      .on('end', resolve)
      .on('error', reject);
  });
}

function coreStylesAll() {
  console.log('before promise call');
  let result = folders.map(folder => coreStyles(folder));
  console.log('next step');

  return Promise.all(result); 
}
```

Comment: What is `resolve().pipe()` all about? It's going to throw, surely?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 `.on('end', resolve)` seems is working well!

Comment: Looks a whole lot better.